# Exception: No such property: level for class: org.slf4j.impl.Slf4jLogger

Tags: slf4j, docx4j

After updating docx4j from 2.8.0 to 3.1.0, I have a problem with the following codes:

```
WordprocessingMLPackage wml = WordprocessingMLPackage.load(new File(preferenceService.getLocalTemplateDir(), profileVO.templateFile + ".docx"));
/**
some codes for processing the file here...
*/

wml.save(targetFile);
```

Theses codes work fine in the version 2.8.0, but with 3.1.0 I got an exceptiopn when the line wml.save(targetFile) was called. I can not step into this code, because i get the following exception immediately before steping into:

```
Message: No such property: level for class: org.slf4j.impl.Slf4jLogger
```

I am using slf4j-api with the version 1.7.7 (For docx4j 3.1.0 is 1.7.5 of slf4j-api as standard dependency) and slf4j-log4j12 with the version 1.7.5.

What could i do now, since i can not step into this method and get the exception immediately? What does this exception mean? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved!

The new version of docx4j uses a new log package. It doesn't have the property "level". So i just need to rewrite the line, where "level" was used!